# geometry nodes grid sine selection points

Tags: node-editor, geometry

I would like to create sine graph function projected on grid of instances. https://imgur.com/a/NiQcc8G

Question:
**1.Math function nodes**

How can I use Set position with math function to create sine graph, driven position of Z axie by integer.

**2. Geometry proximity**

Meaning, simple driver that will be animated.

Which solution is better or which one do you prefer?

Comment: So, do you want to make it look like… a sine wave shaped giant pipe is buried under New York City? Or like New York City was built on top of a frozen water ripple?

Comment: more like some motion graphics type effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with this node setup:

[image]

you will get this:

[image]

and if you unmute the translate instances node, you will get this:

[image]

if you adapt the node tree, you can easily change it to a higher resolution:

[image]

you can just use the Vector math distance instead of proximity to get a similar effect.

[image]

Comment: thanks, looks good.  Is there way to do it directly with math nodes, selection of set position node?

Comment: do you mean instead proximity?

Comment: yes. instead of proximity